# Creating/Migrating rBac in Yii2

Tags: linux, bash, yii

I'm just getting started with Yii2 and I am following a [tutorial here](http://sintret.com/blog_detail/523/yii2_create_project_with_adminlte_basic_and_advanced_easyly) about setting up Yii2/AdminLTE and I am unable to finish the setup as I am getting errors in Terminal on the last step.

The part I am not able to finish is:

> finaly we create rbac dbmanager with simple code, you can see in
>   folder "console/RbacController" with specific level for :
>
> Admin : can do everything Editor : can edit, add and view Author : can
>   add and view viewer ; just viewer  create rbac :

```
"yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations"
"yii rbac/init"
```

> dont forget to chmod -R 777 on your web/assets if linux environment
>   and please free to update your setting on menu setting.

So in terminal on my mac, I tried both:

```
yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations
```

with the error: `-bash: yii: command not found`

and

```
/.yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations
```

with error: `-bash: /.yii: No such file or directory.`

I was able to complete the beginning of the tutorial, it is just this last step.  I am already working in my yii2-advanced-adminlte directory

UPDATED:
Added screenshot of terminal window
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally the yii command is located in

fro advanced template in project directory parent of backend, frontend, console and not in console

be sure of find the right dir and then accessing this try launche your command

```
 yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations
```

eventually adjust your path to rbac/ migrations

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, can you maybe provide an example or link?

Comment: You are using Yii2 ? and advanced template?

Comment: you have accessed the project dir ... and ls show the yii command?

Comment: This time I get Error: unknown option: --migrationPath  I am adding a screenshot to my questions so you can see my terminal window

Answer (score 0):

Found it out, the problem was using MAMP I had to manually set the php bin to 5.5.23 in terminal because once I started down the path scaisEdge showed me I was getting a No such File or Folder error.

Eventually this is the command that worked for me (check your php MAMP path):

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.23/bin/php yii migrate
```

Source link: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47043-error-on-using-db-migration-w-mysql#entry222568